# Ionic: Unwanted loading bar on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

An unwanted loading bar, that gets stuck, is showing up under my navbar in my Ionic app on Android.

[image: Page with loading bar]

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title>History</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="history" (click)="clearHistoryAlert()">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see in **[this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-black-opacity-pixel-in-the-top-left-corner-when-sidemenu-is-shown/52671)** or in **[this one](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gray-box-in-beginning-of-ion-content/55281/10)** from Ionic forum, it's not a loading bar, but a bug in Ionic. There's also a **[github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6416)** still open related to this.

According to the comments, for now you can use the following style rule as a workaround to fix it:

```
.scroll-content{
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```